# jquery validate question

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form which is kind of an excel spreadsheet with 650 fields. I need to validate two fields which are required. Also, I want to prevent multiple form submissions by hiding the save button at first click.

I have the following :

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
    $('#formSub').hide();                        
    $('#bidForm').validate({
        rules: {
                vendorName: { required:true }
        },
        messages: {
                vendorName:  "Vendor Name is required!"
        }
    }).form();  

    if ($("#bidForm").valid()) {
        $("#formSub").html('<table style="font-size:11px;"><tr><td><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0"></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Saving! Please wait...</td></tr></table>');

        var options = {
                success:function() {
                    $("#formSub").html('<input type="button" name="btnBFGoBack" id="btnBFGoBack" class="submitButton btnGoBack" value="Go Back" style="float:left; margin-right:20px;" /><input type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" class="submitButton save" value="Save" style="float:right;" />'); 
                },
                url:'saveForm.cfm'
        };
        $("#bidForm").ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    }
});
```

i am having couple issues.

1. after i click the save button, it takes almost 4-5 seconds before the "saving! please wait" shows up. I don't understand why
     $("#formSub").html('  Saving! Please wait...');
   does not trigger immediately.
2. btnBFGoBack has a click  function. After i show the button with $("#formSub").html(), the click function does not work anymore.

Is the validate() having issues since i have so many fields in the form? How can I make sure the save button is hidden, validate my two fields, and show the save button again?

Comment: i solved second issue by adding onclick="goBack();" to the button. i am still curious why the click() event didn't trigger second time though.

Comment: 1. Move the "saving! please wait" message to before the valid() call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it wasn't practical to use validation plug-in when i have 600+ formfield and have to validate only 1 or 2 fields. so:

```
 $('#btnSave').click(function() {
     if ( $('#vendorName').val() == '') {
         $('#vendorErr').html('Please pick a vendor!');
     } else {
        $("#formSub").html('<table style="font-size:11px;"><tr><td><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0"></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Saving! Please wait...</td></tr></table>');

        var options = {
            success:function() {
                $("#formSub").html('<input type="button" name="btnBFGoBack" id="btnBFGoBack" class="submitButton btnGoBack" value="Go Back" style="float:left; margin-right:20px;" onclick="goBack();" /><input type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" class="submitButton save" value="Save" style="float:right;" />'); 
            },
            url:'saveForm.cfm'
        };
        $("#bidForm").ajaxSubmit(options);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup the validation op page load, not on the submit handler. Also attach the submit handler through [jquery validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). Still seems like a long time for what you are doing. Maybe debug a little in the validate js file and make sure it is not looping all the fields within the form.

```
$(function(){ // ready
    $('#bidForm').validate({/*options*/
        submitHandler: function(form){
            //send ajax here
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: the problem with this approach was i couldn't find some kind of beforeSubmit function with validate plugin. I need to hide the save button so that people won't keep clicking on that.

Comment: @FALCONSEYE - The validation is not the part that will take time. It is the ajax request. This is where you should disable the button. In the submit handler.

Comment: as you said, i think validate.js is looping through form fields. if i remove the validate and add a simple if statement for $('#vendorName').val() == '', it doesn't wait at all.

Comment: according to firebug the ajax request takes only 81ms.

Comment: It must be the 650+ fields that are slowing it down then. Can you possibly just wrap the two fields you are trying to validate in their own form? You could copy the values over to hidden fields in th other form. That or just validate manually like `$('#vendorName').val()`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of fields and only want to validate 2 fields with the validate plugin, you can add an "ignore" class which tells the validate plugin that a particular field(s) should not be validated. That should speed up the process and you can still make use of all the other nifty validate plugin features.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call validate after click event, but after page is loaded and use submitHandler to send ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bidForm').validate({
        rules: {
                vendorName: { required:true }
        },
        messages: {
                vendorName:  "Vendor Name is required!"
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // handler body
        }
    });  
});
```

Without a testcase it's hard to guess.